# ¿Cómo rellenar un listview a través de un json?

Tags: json, arraylist, kotlin

Llevo poco tiempo iniciándome en Android Studio + kotlin y aún mezclo algunos conceptos.
Estoy tratando de realizar lo siguiente:

1. Ejecuto una función llamada  **ejecutar_servicio()** donde
   obtengo un array desde una respuesta json. (Esto si lo he conseguido)
2. Intento pasar este
   array a mi **MyCustomAdapter**, el cual genera un listView pero no
   consigo pasar los datos.

   ```
   class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
   //Este es un array que he tratado de hacer global y donde guardo la consulta web
   var nombres_establecimientos = arrayListOf<String>()

   override fun onCreateView( inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,  savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {
       //Ejecuto el servicio que hace la llamada json
       ejecutar_servicio()
       val listView = root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
       //Aqui he pensando en pasar el array que en la otra función se rellenó, a la clase, pero no lo consigo.
       listView.adapter =
           getActivity()?.let { MyCustomAdapter(it, nombres_establecimientos) } // this needs to be my custom adapter telling my list what to render

       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return root
   }



   private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, arr: ArrayList<String>): BaseAdapter() {
       private val nombres_establecimientos = arr
       ....
       override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {

       val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
       val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false)
       println(">Nombres_establecimientos3: ${nombres_establecimientos}")


       val nameTextView = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
       nameTextView.text = nombres_establecimientos.get(position)

       val descriptionTextView = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
       descriptionTextView.text = nombres_establecimientos.get(position)

       return rowMain
   }

   class Establecimiento( var id: Int, var nombre: String, var direccion: String ) {
       override fun toString(): String {
           //return "Category [id: ${this.id}, nombre: ${this.nombre}, direccion: ${this.direccion}]"
           return this.nombre
       }
   }
   }

   //Esta es la función donde recibo los datos de la consulta a la api json, hay varios println donde confirmo que si recibo los datos.
   private fun ejecutar_servicio(): Array<MyCustomAdapter.Establecimiento?> {

   val url = "url/api/respuesta_json"
   val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

   val client = OkHttpClient()
   client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
       override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
           val body = response?.body()?.string()
           println(body)

           val gson = Gson()
           val arrayEstablecimientoType = object : TypeToken<Array<MyCustomAdapter.Establecimiento>>() {}.type

           var resultados: Array<MyCustomAdapter.Establecimiento> = gson.fromJson(body, arrayEstablecimientoType)
           resultados.forEachIndexed  { idx, item ->
               println("> Item ${idx}: ${item}")
               nombres_establecimientos.add(item.toString())
           }
           println(">Nombres_establecimientos: ${nombres_establecimientos}")


       }

       override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
           println("Failed to execute request")
       }
   })

   return emptyArray()
   }
   ```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Lo que puedo ver acerca de lo que deseas realizar es correcto, cual es el problema especifico?

Comment: Que el array llega vacío. Cuando hago un **println(nombres_establecimientos)** después **listview.adapter** en **OnCreateView**, está vacío.

Comment: @Jorgesys podrías orientarme para intentar generar el listview sólo despues de que termine **ejecutar_servicio()** y no antes?

Comment: Si, recuerda que este proceso para obtener la información es asíncrono, regularmente hay callbacks que indican cuando el proceso de petición termino, en este caso esto se realiza en onResponse() aquí es donde debes realizar el llenado de información en tu adapter, @AntonioRuiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `ejecutar_servicio()` estás haciendo una llamada de red, lo cual se ejecuta en segundo plano, esto implica que el código inicilizará el Adapter **mientras** se ejecuta el servicio, por lo tanto, la lista aún permanecerá vacía.

Deberías de inicializar el Apdater **después** de que termine el servicio.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
//Este es un array que he tratado de hacer global y donde guardo la consulta web
var nombres_establecimientos = arrayListOf<String>()


override fun onCreateView( inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,  savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {

    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_establecimientos, container, false)
    val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
    textView.text = "Establecimientos cercanos"

    //Si saco el listview fuera, puedo mostrar el Array de prueba llamado "names" que hay en MyCustomAdapter, pero tal cual está he comprobado que no se ejecuta lo que hay dentro de ejecutar_servicio{}
    ejecutar_servicio {
        val listView = root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        listView.adapter = getActivity()?.let { MyCustomAdapter(it, establecimientos) } // this needs to be my custom adapter telling my list what to render
        println(">Establecimientos01: ${establecimientos}")
    }

    return root

}



class MyCustomAdapter(val context: Context, private val lista: ArrayList<Establecimiento>): BaseAdapter() {

    // responsible for how many rows in my list
    override fun getCount() = lista.size

    // you can also ignore this
    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    // you can ignore this for now
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = ""

    // responsible for rendering out each row
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false)
        with(rowMain){
            val nameTextView = findViewById(cchcc.learn.amu.R.id.textView1)
            nameTextView.text = lista[position].nombre

            val descriptionTextView = findViewById(cchcc.learn.amu.R.id.textView2)
            descriptionTextView.text = lista[position].nombre
        }

        return rowMain
    }

}

data class Establecimiento( var id: Int, var nombre: String, var direccion: String )


//Esta es la función donde recibo los datos de la consulta a la api json, hay varios println donde confirmo que si recibo los datos.
fun ejecutar_servicio(metodo: () -> Unit): Array<Establecimiento?> {

    val url = "url/api/json"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {

        val gson = Gson()
        val arrayEstablecimientoType = object : TypeToken<Array<Establecimiento>>() {}.type

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)
            var resultados: Array<Establecimiento> = gson.fromJson(body, arrayEstablecimientoType)
            establecimientos = resultados.toList() as ArrayList<Establecimiento>

            //Este print si muestra los resultados
            println(">Establecimientos: ${establecimientos}")

            activity?.runOnUiThread(metodo.invoke())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            println("Failed to execute request")
        }

    })
    return emptyArray()
}
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón con tu enfoque, pero con tu forma sigue sin llegarle el array a tiempo, o le llega vacío..

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner un punto de interrupción en la linea donde haces el print `println(">Nombres_establecimientos: ${nombres_establecimientos}")
`? En ese momento, ¿el array está completo?

Comment: Si, en ese momento si está completo.

Comment: I/System.out: >Nombres_establecimientos: [Bar Las Tapitas, Restaurante El Tenedor]

Comment: Además me acabo de dar cuenta que todo lo que hay dentro del **ejecutar_servicio {}** en OnCreateView, no se ejecuta.

Comment: Si llega al punto de `metodo.invoke()`, debería ejecutarse, es posible que si vas paso a paso en del debugger esa parte no se interprete bien y parezca que no se está ejecutando, te recomendaría poner otro punto de interrupción en la primera linea `val listView = root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)`, en las llaves de `ejecutar servicio`, y cuando llegues a `metodo.invoke()`, en vez de darle al siguiente paso, le des al play para que pare en el próximo punto de interrupción

Comment: No había agregado la línea **metodo.invoke()** en ejecutar_servicio(), y ahora al incluirla se me cierra la app justo después de abrirse.

Comment: ¿Y cual es el error que te está dando?

Comment: Es que el LogCat no me da errores..

Comment: Lo tengo en Verbose y esta es la unica linea que me muestra: 05-22 10:02:07.401 20974-20996/com.tutapeas I/System.out: >Nombres_establecimientos: [Bar Las Tapitas, Restaurante El Tenedor]

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108321/discussion-between-doruko-and-antonio-ruiz).

Comment: me ha surgido dos dudas mas jeje con una función que he desarrollado después a raiz de las anteriores. Es acerca de abrir una nueva actividad al clickear sobre algún lemento del listview. ¿Abro una nueva pregunta? ¿Podrás ayudarme? :)

Comment: Podemos hablarlo en la misma sala de chat previa